# How to output a backslash from UTF-8 database using PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8, backslash

I succesfully wrote a backslash ("**\**") to a **UTF-8** encoded table using **mysql_real_escape_string()**. When I access the database with **phpMyAdmin** it shows exactly one backslash as the field's content.

But when I read the database within my own code I get nothing! It's an empty string:

```
(strlen($myBackslash) == 0) // true
```

The database is in UTF-8 and the connection is set to UTF-8 too. Also HTTP and HTML headers are set accordingly:

```
// the character set of the connection (in PHP)
mysql_set_charset('utf8', $conn);

// the HTTP header
Content-Type    text/html;charset=utf-8

// the HTML header
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The problem is in the code you didn't show, before the `(strlen($myBackslash) == 0)`

Comment: Oh man, thank you Eugen! I found the error while compiling some example code from the DB class I had been using since ages - from the old times before utf-8 and non-magic-quotes. And there it was: stripslashes() ruined all the results. Couldn't believe it when I saw it.
Since I'm a newbie and you got quite some high reputation: should I delete my post or leave it?
Greets from Munich, Eddie

Comment: Leave it! This might happen to another user too.

Answer (score 0):

```
/*
    db_connection.php
    Only Database Connection
*/

$Connection=mysql_connect("localhost","user","") or die(include("error.php"));
    /*
     Create mysql connection or show include in db_connection.php
    */
mysql_select_db("selected_db_name",$Connection)or die(include("error.php"));
    /*
     set this connection default charset utf8 you can set
    */
mysql_set_charset("utf8",$Connection);
```